# Qual o procedimento para depurar uma "pilha de execução", Javascript ou Php através do navegador ou IDE Aptana?

Tags: google-chrome, debug, ide

Quando desenvolvemos um código , ele é executado conforme uma pilha de instruções.

Existe alguma forma, onde através do navegador ou de uma IDE, onde consigamos acompanhar passo a passo o processamento do código, e ver até que ponto ele foi executado ou parou devido a algum erro ?

Sei que cada linguagem oferece métodos para tratamento de erro, no entanto esse método faz parte da pilha de execução, isto posto, minha dúvida exclui como opção os métodos através do próprio código.

Comment: cada linguagem tem a sua metodoligia, voce quer depurar o que? html js php?

Comment: php, ajax, js basicamente

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para o javascript use o depurador do Chrome. Basta apertar **F12** e ele aparecerá. Vá na opçao **console** e faça a sua debogagem.

Para o PHP não é tão simples assim mas é fácil. Antes de mais nada queria comentar sobre a IDE. Existem muitas no mercado. Gratuitas ou não e cada programador tem sua própria preferência. Eu uso [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/features/index.html#o5). É gratuita e completa. Sem muitas burocracias para instalar extenções inclusive depuradores. Aqui vc pode fazer o [download](https://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html) da versão que lhe convém.

Para rodar um debogador em uma IDE vc precisa:

1. Configurar o debogador ou depurador no arquivo de inicialização do php, o **php.ini**.
2. Configurar o **IDE** para aceitar o debogador já instalado. NOTA: Se vc usar netbeans, essa etapa não é necessária, pois ele reconhece a configuração dentro do **php.ini** automaticamente.

Independente do IDE utilizado vc terá que configurar o xdebug no **php.ini** e essa é a parte mais trabalhosa. A segunda parte, do IDE Aptana vou passar o link com o passo a passo.

1. Crie um projeto com qualquer nome e em seguida uma página contendo `phpinfo();` somente;
2. Abra o browser que apresenta as informações do **phpinfo** e copie tudo (`crtl+a` em seguida `crtl+c`)
3. Vá para esse [link](https://xdebug.org/wizard.php) do **xdebug** e cole o seu conteudo no espaço apropriado e aperte o botão **Analyse my phpinfo output**. Veja foto abaixo:
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
4. Essa ferramenta vai encontrar a **dll** extata para a sua versáo de php. Veja a foto abaixo:
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
5. Click sobre o arquivo **dll** oferecido e faça o download.
6. Procure a pasta onde se localiza as extenções do PHP (**ext**). Em algumas instalações fica diretamente dentro do diretório PHP tipo (**php>ext**) em outras fica dentro da pasta bin (**php>bin>ext**). Note que a ferramenta te mostrou em verde o caminho do **php.ini** e da pasta **ext** segundo a instalação do php na sua máquina.
7. Cole o arquivo **.dll** do xdebug que vc fez o download dentro dessa pasta **ext**. O arquivo de nicialização do php (**php.ini**) vai procurar esse arquivo **.dll** dentro desta pasta para habilitar a função de debogagens.
8. Logo, vc precisa escrever dentro do **php.ini** o caminho (path) até esse arquivo **.dll**. E além disso passar algumas informações que o IDE irá utilizar para a sessão de debogagem ou depuaração. Se vc não fizer isso, o IDE vai lançar uma mensagem de erro. Copie e cole as seguintes linhas no fim do seu arquivo **php.ini** depois salve:
9. `[XDebug]`
10. `zend_extension="[AMP Path]\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"` ESSE É O SEU PATH ATÉ O .dll
11. `xdebug.remote_enable = 1`
12. `xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"`
13. `xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"`
14. `xdebug.remote_port = 9000`

    Feito esses passos, o seu IDE e seu PHP já devem estar configurados para a sessão de debogagem. Reinicializar o servidor e rodar novamente a pagina que contém o `phpinfo()`. Vc perceberá que teve uma mudança na apresentação da página phpinfo. E a mensagem mostrando que o xdebug foi instalado com sucesso, veja foto abaixoÇ:
    [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Está pronto. A partir de agora o depurador ja foi insalado e configurado na sua máquina. Se estivesse usando o netbeans a sua configuarção iria parar por aqui. Para seguir com a configuração do Aptana siga este [passo a passo](http://devcircle.blogspot.ca/2013/02/enable-xdebug-in-aptana-studio-3x.html).

E embora não seja o escopo da pergunta, posto aqui uma foto de uma simples sessão de depuração com xDebug e NetBeans. Testando um erro de elementos com mesmo id no DOM:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Opa existe sim. Caso seja pra depurar um JS você pode utilizar o próprio console do navegador clicando com a tecla f12. Nele tu pode navegar ate Sources( caso seja google chrome ) ou em Scripts ( caso seja firefox com a extensão firebug instalada )

Se for por uma IDE ai vai depender qual tu está utilizando. Eu trabalho com JAVA e uso o eclipse, então eu ponho o breakpoint na linha que eu quero debugar e executo a aplicação. Quando For executada a linha que eu pus o breakpoint a ide entra em ação e te mostra o que passa por trás das linhas de código no debug.

Comment: Como eu coloco esses breaks no chorme?

Comment: talvez isso possa ser util [depurando javascript com google chrome](http://devmedia.com.br/depurando-javascript-com-google-chrome/28367)